# How to set PDF export in polymode-mode to use xelatex engine?

Tags: latex, pdf, markdown, polymode

Consider the below MWE of `.Rmd` file containing Arabic text which needs xelatex engine to be rendered by `pandoc`. As the documentation of the latter says putting this option would make it: `--latex-engine=xelatex`.

**MWE**

```
---
title: "Minimal Working Example `.Rmd` in Arabic"
author: "Author Name"
date: "Friday, July 08, 2016"
output: pdf_document
latex-engine: xelatex
---

----------

# مقدمة عن التقرير
# نتائج البحث
# الخلاصة

# Introduction of the Report

# Results

# Summary
```

So this how it appears in Emacs editor:

[image]

**This is my setup:**

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. Emacs GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian
3. Pandoc 1.16.0.2
4. `polymode-mode` and `markdown-mode` from MELPA latest as of this date
5. `init.el` setup in relation to polymode-mode
6. ESS 16.04

**init.el - polymode-mode**

```
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org" . poly-org-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd`enter code here`" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
```

**init.el - customizataions**

```
...
 '(ess-rutils-keys t)
 '(ess-swv-pdflatex-commands (quote ("xelatex" "pdflatex" "texi2pdf" "make")))
 '(ess-swv-processor (quote knitr))
...
```

**Primary Issue**
When I export the `.Rmd` buffer to pdf by <kbd>M-n-e</kbd>, I am prompted for 3 options: `Rmarkdown-ESS`, `Rmarkdown`, and `pandoc`. I picked `Rmarkdown-ESS` this was the error log:

```
/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS 4G_report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output /home/username/.emacs.d/docs/rstat/4th_examCom_program_2015_2016/4G_report[exported].pdf --template /home/username/R/my_R_library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.15.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char س (U+633)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.293 \end{verbatim}

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
R>
```

so as you can see the error suggests using `--latex-engine=xelatex` in pandoc instead of the default pdflatex. So how to set xelatex engine as default in polymode export? I tried to set the engine to xelatex in the YAML header but it didn't work. Or is there a way to change the value of a variable like `pm-exporter/pandoc`?

**Secondary Issue**
When I export to `html` I want the Arabic text direction to be from right-to-left and the English part of the text to be from left-to-right. Although I enjoy this bidi-direction inside Emacs editor, well this is one of the good reasons to pick this editor, but unfortunately I dont' get the same effect in the html export, and I don't know whether the same issue will arise int the pdf. So what do I need to get that effect in the exported document?

Answer (score 1):

Is it as simple as the following in your init.el?

```
(setq TeX-engine 'xelatex)
(setq latex-run-command "xelatex")
```

Answer (score 0):

When exporting from Org-Mode, you can add the following line to your init, to set XeLaTex as the default compiling engine:

```lisp
(setq org-latex-compiler "xelatex")
```